# wifi not working in ubuntu 16.04, dell laptop, TP-link router

Tags: 16.04

I stopped the regular software update and opened next day to continue it and the wifi was not working, then i googled for solution and tried everything, but i couldn't resolve it. I don't know whether i messed up everything without clear knowledge. I need help.

with this command    `sudo apt update`  I get    `Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease

  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease

  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease

  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
50 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

and

`$ apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)`

Comment: Have you tried restarting network-manager? You can do this either by `systemctl restart network-manager` or `service network-manager restart`. Let me know how this handles.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Nothing happens with both of those codes

Comment: How were you exactly performing the regular software update? And how did you pause it?

Comment: I checked for update and it listed some so i started updating. Since it took so long i put my laptop to sleep and next day i started the update again but wifi was not working. I am using ubuntu with vmware, in windows wifi is working without any problem.

Comment: Ah. Some important information you left out there chief. So to be clear you have no internet connection? Have you tried rebooting? Any logs with more information would be extremely useful.

Comment: yes, this happened a month ago and i still couldn't figure it. Also i am afraid that on trying to fix it i used different commands, changed different files. I didn't even note what all i did. Is it fixable?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please take a look at it

Comment: I do not know what to do at this point in time...  Could be multiple problems, some with VMware and some with Ubuntu...